# How to migrate TestNG @DataProvider to JUnit Jupiter @ParameterizedTest

Tags: testng, junit5, testng-dataprovider, junit-jupiter

I have unit tests using TestNG that I try to move to JUnit Jupiter (JUnit 5), and I wonder which is the best way to do:

**TestNG**:

```java
@DataProvider
public Object[][] invalidPortNumbers() {
    return new Object[][] {
            { "--http", "" },
            { "--http", "-42" },
            { "--http", "0" },
            { "--http", "not_a_port_number" },
            { "--https", "67000" }
    };
}

@Test(dataProvider = "invalidPortNumbers",
      expectedExceptions = ParameterException.class,
      expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp = ".* is not valid port number .*")
public void shouldFailToValidatePortNumber(final String... args) {
    new CommandLineParser(args);
}
```

I saw that moving to **JUnit Jupiter**, I can do:

```java
static Stream<Arguments> invalidPortNumbers2() {
    return Stream.of(
            Arguments.of((Object) new String[] { "--http", "-42" }),
            Arguments.of((Object) new String[] { "--http", "0" }),
            Arguments.of((Object) new String[] { "--http", "not_a_port_number" }),
            Arguments.of((Object) new String[] { "--https", "67000" })
    );
}

@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("invalidPortNumbers2")
void shouldFailToValidatePortNumber(final String... args) {
    assertThatThrownBy(() -> new CommandLineParser(args))
            .isInstanceOf(ParameterException.class)
            .hasMessageMatching(".* is not valid port number .*");
}
```

Is there any other way to simplify this and keep the previous dataProvider structure to minimise the changes?

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you make your existing `invalidPortNumbers()` method `static` and reference it from `@MethodSource`?

Comment: I got the following exception:
`org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: Error converting parameter at index 0: No implicit conversion to convert object of type java.lang.String to type [Ljava.lang.String;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With parameterized tests in JUnit Jupiter, if the return type of the method referenced via `@MethodSource` is a 2 dimensional array, the values of the inner arrays will be passed as multiple arguments to a single test method invocation. This means that there is no straightforward way to migrate a test method that accepts var-args (or an explicit array) from TestNG's `@DataProvider` to JUnit Jupiter's `@MethodSource`.

Your `invalidPortNumbers2()` is a suitable workaround for this limitation, but there are other workarounds that you may prefer.

---

**Updated Answer:**

The simplest way to process all arguments as a single array is via the `ArgumentsAccessor` API.

If you make your existing `invalidPortNumbers()` method `static`, you can use it "as is" and convert the arguments to an array as follows.

```java
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("invalidPortNumbers")
void shouldFailToValidatePortNumber(ArgumentsAccessor accessor) {
    Object[] args = accessor.toArray();
    // Use args ...
}
```

Though, in JUnit Jupiter you might find using a `@CsvSource` preferable to using the `@MethodSource` for such use cases. So, to achieve the same goal, you can rewrite your test as follows and get rid of the `invalidPortNumbers()` method.

```java
@ParameterizedTest
@CsvSource({
    "--http, ''",
    "--http, -42",
    "--http, 0",
    "--http, not_a_port_number",
    "--https, 67000"
})
void shouldFailToValidatePortNumber(ArgumentsAccessor accessor) {
    Object[] args = accessor.toArray();
    // Use args ...
}
```

---

**Original Answer:**

For starters, the following utility method will help to simplify things (declared in a class named `VarArgsParamsTests` but could be moved to a common utility class). Note that `arguments()` is statically imported via `org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.Arguments.arguments`.

```java
static Arguments arrayArguments(String... array) {
    return arguments((Object) array);
}
```

Given that, if you want to keep your existing `invalidPortNumbers()` method with as little modification as possible, you can redefine its signature as `static String[][] invalidPortNumbers()` and introduce the following method that you actually reference from `@MethodSource`.

```java
static Stream<Arguments> invalidPortNumbersArguments() {
    return Arrays.stream(invalidPortNumbers()).map(VarArgsParamsTests::arrayArguments);
}
```

If you're willing to modify your existing `invalidPortNumbers()` method more, you could change it to the following that also uses the `arrayArguments()` utility method.

```java
static Stream<Arguments> invalidPortNumbers() {
    return Stream.of(
        arrayArguments("--http", ""),
        arrayArguments("--http", "-42"),
        arrayArguments( "--http", "0"),
        arrayArguments( "--http", "not_a_port_number"),
        arrayArguments( "--https", "67000")
    );
}
```

Comment: Please note that I added solutions using the ArgumentsAccessor API.